# Unable to get HttpNegotiateAuth module working. ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below statement in my python file,

```
from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth
```

though i was able to make the authentication work

- getting an error - no module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'. to fix this, i tried "pip install pywin32==225"
- Got another error - moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'. to fix this i tried pip install pypiwin32
- And now i'm getting the below error

> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_negotiate_sspi__init__.py:4: in 
>       from .requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth  # noqa
>   c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests_negotiate_sspi\requests_negotiate_sspi.py:11: in 
>       import sspi
>   c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\sspi.py:16: in 
>       import win32security, sspicon
>   E   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

What would be the best way to get this fixed? i had a look at other similar queries on stackoverflow but could not get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this, and then it started to work fine without any issues

pip install pywin32==223